# What is the best practice to query this type of data in laravel?

Tags: laravel, group-by

I have 3 tables structure like below:-

> products

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | apple |
| 2 | orange |

> branches

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Branch 1 |
| 2 | Branch 2 |

> stocks

| id | branch_id | product_id | qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 20 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 30 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 | 40 |

Expected result:-

| No. | Name | Branch 1 | Branch 2 | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | 10 | 30 | 40 |
| 2 | orange | 20 | 40 | 60 |

Below is my code it is working and can get the expected result but I don't like the way I do especially the part $stock[0]->product->name, I think there must be another proper way to do this better not to loop the branches in blade, is it possible to get everything done in query?

> StockController

```
$branches = Branch::get();
$stocks = Stock::get()->groupBy('product_id');

//$stocks->toArray() output
array:2 [
  1 => array:2 [
     0 => array:4 [
        "id" => 1
        "product_id" => 1
        "branch_id" => 1
        "qty" => 10
     ]
     1 => array:4 [
        "id" => 1
        "product_id" => 1
        "branch_id" => 2
        "qty" => 30
     ]
  ]
  2 => array:2 [
     0 => array:4 [
        "id" => 1
        "product_id" => 2
        "branch_id" => 1
        "qty" => 20
     ]
     1 => array:4 [
        "id" => 1
        "product_id" => 2
        "branch_id" => 2
        "qty" => 40
     ]
  ]
]
```

> stock_index.blade.php

```
@foreach ($stocks as $stock)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
                <td>{{ $stock[0]->product->name }}</td>
                @foreach ($branches as $branch)
                    <td>{{ $stock->firstWhere('branch_id', $branch->id)->qty ?? 0 }}</td>
                @endforeach
                <td>{{ $stock->sum('qty') }}</td>
            </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: can you please post the output of dd($stocks)?

Comment: @Mike question updated, i convert to array first before i output for you easy to read, the real data is actually collection of stock model inside the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
$branches = Branch::pluck('name', 'id');

$query_string = "";

foreach ($branches as $key => $value) {
    $query_string .= "sum(CASE WHEN stocks.branch_id = '". $key ."' THEN stocks.qty END) as " . str_replace(' ', '_', $value) . "_sum , ";
}

$query_string .= 'sum(stocks.qty) as total';

$stocks = Stock::join('products', 'stocks.product_id', '=', 'products.id')->select(
    'products.name as product_name',
    DB::raw($query_string)
)->groupBy('product_id')->orderBy('product_id','asc')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use this code: ‌

```
$query = "";

foreach (Branch::query()->pluck('name', 'id') as $key => $value) {
    $query .= "sum(CASE WHEN stocks.branch_id = '". $key ."' THEN stocks.qty END) as " . str_replace(' ', '_', $value) . "_sum , ";
}

$query .= 'sum(stocks.qty) as total';

$stocks = Stock::query()->join('products', 'stocks.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
    ->select(
        'products.name as product_name',
        DB::raw($query)
    )->groupBy('product_id')
    ->orderBy('product_id','asc')
    ->get();
```